# How do I get started building an application that can send/receive MMS?

Tags: mms, twilio, pbx

I love Twilio and I know there are tons of other cloud communication platforms that are good, but none of them seem to support MMS.

1) Does anyone know why it is so difficult to support MMS? It seems like an obvious feature to support, but there must be some technical limitations that I'm not aware of.

2) What would you need to build (where do I get started) to have a web application send/receive MMS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that SMS and voice use a common protocol, but MMS has different technical implementations at different carriers, making interoperation difficult.

Comment: Thanks, would you say it is too difficult to try? Any direction on where to get started is appreciated.